# Difference between sort compare function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

var arr =  [undefined,null, NaN , Infinity];

*sample.sort((a,b)=> a-b)*

**Answer :  [Infinity, NaN, null, undefined]**

*sample.sort((a,b)=> a>b ? 1 : -1)*

**Answer :  [null, NaN, Infinity, undefined]**

Can anyone explain why there is a difference between the sort function?

Comment: Because `-` doesn't behave like `>`...?

Comment: What's the sence for the comparing?

Comment: Then where should be use - and > ??? Is there any specific datatype ??

Answer (score 1):

sort compare method does the following possible comparisons for both cases. This explains the discrepancy in output

[image]

```js
const output = [];
[Infinity, NaN, null, undefined].forEach((a, i, arr) =>
  arr.forEach((b) => output.push({ 
    a, 
    b, 
    "a - b": a - b, 
    "a>b ? 1 : -1": (a>b ? 1 : -1) 
  }))
);

console.log(output)
console.table(output);
```

[image]